# Visualforce Page Gray out/disable(?) field based off another field

Tags: visualforce

I have a picklist and I want a specific value to render two date fields and another picklist field unable to be edited, or "grayed out". How do I accomplish this?

EDIT

```
            <apex:inputField value="{!contractItem.Contract_Type__c}" onchange="changeVar()" tabOrderHint="40"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!contractItem.Contract_Start_Date__c}" tabOrderHint="41"/>
            <apex:inputField value="**{!contractItem.Service_Frequency__c}**" tabOrderHint="47"/>
            <apex:inputField value="**{!contractItem.Billing_Frequency__c}**" tabOrderHint="47"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!contractItem.Service_Date_Time__c}" tabOrderHint="42"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!contractItem.Contract_Term_months__c}" tabOrderHint="48"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!contractItem.Requested_First_Service__c}" tabOrderHint="43"/>
```

The bolded are disabled. Here is the controller

```
    public void changeVar(){
    if(contractItem.Contract_Type__c == 'Wood Boring Insect'){
        contractItem.Contract_Term_months__c = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `disabled` attribute of the field to an expression and change it to true onchange of the picklist.

e.g. (VF page)

```
<apex:outputPanel id='panel'>
    <apex:actionFunction name='changeVar' action='{!changeVar}' rerender='panel'/>
    <apex:selectList value='{!valueVar}' onchange='changeVar()'>
        <apex:selectOptions value='{!items}'/>
    <apex:selectList>
    <apex:inputField value='{!inputVal}' html-disabled='{!disabledVar}'/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Controller code:

```
public void changeVar(){
    if(valueVar == 'SOME VALUE'){
        disabledVar = true;
    }
}
```

Another option is using some JS to do it:

```
<apex:selectList value='{!valueVar}' onchange='changeVar(event)'>
        <apex:selectOptions value='{!items}'/>
<apex:selectList>
<apex:inputField value='{!inputVal}' id='inputToDisable'/>

<script>
    function changeVar(e){
        if(e.target.value == 'SOME VALUE'){
            document.querySelectorAll(input[id$=inputToDisable]")[0].disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In the controller code, is that where I might want a condition for if the picklist field is <field mentioned>?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis   Correct, I edited my answer to demonstrate

Comment: <apex:inputField value="{!contractItem.Contract_Term_months__c}" disabled="{!disabledVar}" tabOrderHint="48"/>

I get "Unsupported attribute disabled in <apex:inputField>"

I have been messing around with it for a bit and didn't get this before, but I can't see what I've done wrong.... thoughts?

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis my mistake, you have to use the disabled attribute this way `html-disabled` in an `apex:inputField`. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: It's not a great solution so far. The logic seems fine, but it's shifting things over when I try to add those components and just adding onChange to one of the fields deactivates two fields, even though I took away the functionality to disable anything at all. Any idea why that would happen? I don't have any conditions to disable anything, I just wanted a value to make the value of another field 0. But when I try it, two picklists are totally disabled. I'll edit question with cod.e

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis The presence of the `onchange` attribute disables those two fields, or after reRender they're disabled (if the latter is true, are they dependent picklists?)? Wrapping the elements in an `apex:outputPanel` wraps them in a `span` tag when rendered, so it could potentially affect styling. If you're hitting too many issues, the JS approach may serve you better.

Comment: there is no rerender anywhere, so nothing is rerendering. But, there isn't even a disable variable or anything anymore, so I'm not sure why it's having this effect. Just by adding the onChange, whose function in the controller just changes a totally unrelated field val. to 0, the other two fields are disabled.

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis Sorry I can't help you further, but I'm unable to replicate this behavior.

Comment: No worries -- thanks for your help! I have a few options I'm tinkering with anyway, so at the very least, this gave me more exposure to the concept of how I'd go about it; I'll select it as accepted answer.